# Как группировать по столбцу с Unix time и подсчитать среднее для другого столбца в этой группе?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
timestamp,value
1586166810,0
1586166840,0
1586166920,0
1586167120,0

df = pd.read_csv('g.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    prev_data = row['timestamp']
    new_data = row['timestamp']
    while (new_data - prev_data) <= 3600:
        new_data = row['timestamp'] # + 1
        continue
    # скорее всего - этот момент продуман в pandas как брать блоки данных по условию, но не знаю куда читать.
```

Даны даты в формате *Unix time*.

Как группировать по столбцу `timestamp` по 1 часу и подсчитать среднее по этому часу для столбца `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_csv(r"c:\temp\data.csv")

In [9]: df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="s")

In [10]: res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="1H"))["value"].mean()

In [11]: res
Out[11]:
timestamp
2020-04-06 09:00:00    0
Freq: H, Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, можно еще и так:

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="s")
df['group_mean'] = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.hour)['value'].transform('mean')
print(df)
```

результат:

```
            timestamp  value  group_mean
0 2020-04-06 09:53:30      0           0
1 2020-04-06 09:54:00      0           0
2 2020-04-06 09:55:20      0           0
3 2020-04-06 09:58:40      0           0
```